# Scala generics type mismatch

Tags: scala, generics

In Scala, I'm trying:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
def foo[T <: Any]: ru.WeakTypeTag[T] = ru.weakTypeTag[String]
```

But this yields me:

```
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
 found   : reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[String]
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[T]
 def foo[T <: Any]: ru.WeakTypeTag[T] = ru.weakTypeTag[String]
```

What's up here? I'm relatively sure `String` should satisfy `T`'s type constraint of deriving from `Any`...

I guess `String` failed to bind to the `T` type parameter. In my use case other types may be returned as well though, and I'm not sure how I could get that answer to the compiler up-front before executing the function, if that's what it's expecting.

Comment: You can use wildcard while defining return type: `def foo[T <: Any]: ru.WeakTypeTag[_] = ru.weakTypeTag[String]`

Comment: Hah, that's awesome, thank you. Would you mind posting that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use wildcard, anyway your type is extended from Any.

```
def foo[T <: Any]: ru.WeakTypeTag[_] = ru.weakTypeTag[String]
```

In general the problem is with definition of WeakTypeTag[T] class. It is defined invariantly. So you can not use it in covariant case.

Let's go with an examples.

```
  def bom[T >: String]: List[T] = List[String]() // works fine
  def foo[T >: String]: WeakTypeTag[T] = ru.weakTypeTag[String] // compilation fails
```

I'm defining T as any subtype of String and it works good for `Lists` but fails for `WeakTypeTag` that is invariant.
You can define sub type of `WeakTypeTag` and make it covariant so it will perfectly works.

```
  trait WeakTypeTag1[+X] extends ru.WeakTypeTag {
  }

  def weakTypeTag1[T](implicit attag: WeakTypeTag1[T]) = attag

  def foo[T >: String]: WeakTypeTag1[T] = weakTypeTag1[String] // no it's good
```

Answer (score 6):

Your method `foo` claims that, for any `T <: Any`, it returns a `WeakTypeTag[T]`. That is, if `T` is (for instance) `Int`, it should return a `WeakTypeTag[Int]`. However, your method always returns a `WeakTypeTag[String]`, hence the type mistmatch.

Comment: Thanks. Could I make it allow me to return what I want though? My actual method is recursive, forcing me to make the return type explicit, while it wouldn't know the exact content of the returned type tag before execution...

Comment: @Tycho It's difficult to help you do what you actually want, if you don't share the actual code.